# Elastic Search Script taking date as String

Tags: elasticsearch, scripting

I have couple of `date fields` in my type . I am trying to run a `script` on those date fields find the duration between 2 dates.

Script takes a date field as String and gives No such property: millis for class. i beleive Elastic Search stores in the date in epoch millis.

Here is the script i am trying

```
ctx._source.duraton = ctx._source.sessionTerminationDateTime.value.millis - ctx._source.eventConversionDateTime.value.millis
```

Here is my mapping

```
 "access-event-logs": {
    "mappings": {
      "session-summary": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "long_1": {
              "mapping": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "match": "generation"
            }
          },
          {
            "datetime_1": {
              "mapping": {
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
                "type": "date"
              },
              "match": "*DateTime"
            }
          },
          {
            "string_1": {
              "mapping": {
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "type": "string"
              },
              "match": "*"
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "eventConversionDateTime": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "generation": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "hostname": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "sessionKey": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "include_in_all": false
          },
          "sessionTerminationDateTime": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can i get the duration in millis between 2 date fields

```
doc['eventConversionDateTime'].date.getMillis(). 
{
"_index":"access-event-logs",
"_type":"session-summary",
"_id":"c2de4a9dkarabip1new.lab.fp.f5net.com",
"_version":1,
"found":true,
"_source":{
"sessionKey":"c2de4a9dkarabip1new.lab.fp.f5net.com",
"eventConversionDateTime":"2016-01-06T16:08:43.047-08:00",
"badIpReputation":false,
"virtualServer":"/Common/access_virtual",
"lastUpdateMicros":0
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the `string` to `date`, This worked for me

```
POST /access-event-logs/session-summary/1/_update
{
  "script": "ctx._source.duration=new Date().parse(\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS\",ctx._source.eventConversionDateTime.replace(\"T\", \" \").substring(0,23)).getTime();"
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I am not able to access fields with doc. I tried to run  above script and keeping getting this error.Does this have to do anything with ' not   recognized . "}],\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"failed to execute script\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"groovy_script_execution_exception\",\"reason\":\"failed to run file script [session-duration-script] using lang [groovy]\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"missing_property_exception\",\"reason\":\"No such property: doc for class: a85796c5a6014f123733479c767131bae34307c5\"}}},\"status\":400}",
  "referer": "172.17.86.89",

Comment: could you share one of your sample documents? do all of your documents have both fields?

Comment: Currently i am trying with only one field.                            ctx._source.duraton = doc['eventConversionDateTime'].date.getMillis() .  {
  "_index": "access-event-logs",
  "_type": "session-summary",
  "_id": "c2de4a9dkarabip1new.lab.fp.f5net.com",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "sessionKey": "c2de4a9dkarabip1new.lab.fp.f5net.com",
    "eventConversionDateTime": "2016-01-06T16:08:43.047-08:00",
      "badIpReputation": false,
     "virtualServer": "/Common/access_virtual",
     "lastUpdateMicros": 0
  }
}

Comment: I have updated my answer, even I am getting `no such property` with `doc values`, I am not sure if you could combine `_source` with `doc`.Also please put you sample document,error in question and not in comment section.

Comment: my bad, can't use doc while updating as you cant access it, sorry about that :P

Comment: although I have answered that question, I dont think it is a good idea to post link to different question like this. SO is a huge community, somebody will surely look into your questions and will try to help you.